# I have a problem with my C code. It returns to non-zero value and i do not know why

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out why and how this returns to non-zero value?

Structure goes like this:

Ask user what it likes -> coffee or tea -> if coffee/tea -> how many cups-> 0-3/3-20 -> printf's

otherwise if user doesn't give proper answer -> else'error'.

This is for my school's homework.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char coff = 'c', tea = 't', answer;
    int x = 0;
    printf("Do you drink coffee or tea(c/t)?");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    if((answer == 'c') || (answer =='t'))
    {
            printf("How many cups do you drink daily:");
            scanf("%d", &x);
        
        if(answer =='c' && x<=2)
        {
            printf("You don't drink a lot of coffee, do you?");
        }
        if(answer == 'c' && x>3)
        {
            printf("You drink a lot of coffee!");
        }
        if(answer =='t' && x<=2)
        {
            printf("You do not drink a lot of tea.");
        }
        if(answer =='t' && x>3)
        {
            printf("You drink a lot of tea!");
        }
    }
        else
            printf("An error occurred in the program!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, but copy-paste the code directly in the question instead.

Comment: i've fixed the post.

Comment: You don't cover everthing, for example when `x == 3`.

Comment: By that you mean exactly what?

Comment: You have tested `x<=2` and `x>3` but there is a gap. When `x==3` nothing gets printed.

Comment: Should i jus do like this. `x>2` instead of `x>3`?

Comment: I see no problem. Could you explain more?

Comment: It is unclear what the question is: "It returns to none-zero value." The program returns 0 under all circumstances,  and no function return values have been checked by the program.

Comment: In this case, i'm using online course. I've send them info that their complier is bugged in this situation and they said "it's flawless". Tbh i have no idea what might cause this. Maybe i just need to inform to the support that, their complier in this task is broken.

Comment: Please do not accuse a compiler of being buggy. It is **certain** that any fault will be with your code. As mentioned, the program does not output correct information when told 3 cups. You also need to check that it outputs *exactly* what the problem statement states.

Comment: @WeatherVane: We had a newbie ask a question some years ago that was indeed an actual compiler bug.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I would normally have written *almost certain*, but the program is demonstrably incorrect and Occam's razor applies. That's why, in this case, I wrote **certain**.

Comment: The task description is unclear: "0-3/3-20" does not define two distinct ranges, 3 seems to belong to both. Do you have to check for a maximum of 20? If possible you should add a link to the original task specification. Hint: If you only want to distinguish between a small number (either <3 or <=3) and a big number (either >=3 or >3, respectively) you could use e.g. `if(x < 3) { printf("...not a lot of...\n"); }` **`else`** `{ printf("...a lot of...\n");}` inside an `if` or `switch`/`case` to distinguish between `c`, `t` and other input.

Comment: A compiler bug is very unlikely in this case, but for the site support to claim it is "flawless" is a bold claim!

Comment: _"returns to non-zero value"_  What does that mean? This is the second time this has been asked BTW - it will help you if you clarified (by editing the question, not by adding further comment).  What does the code do when you run it that is contrary to expectation?

Comment: @Clifford It's not a bold claim, it's an unsupportable claim.  If this site in question can produce a C compiler and prove it's "flawless", they've managed to take a very complex software application and prove a negative - that no bugs exist.  Ummm, sure.  TLDR:  they're full of (*!@Q&%(!@

Comment: Hi @kakexd, I found this post really helpful for going through debugging my small projects: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

The test:

```
if(answer == 'c' && x>3)
```

Should be one of:

```
if( answer == 'c' && x >= 3 )
```

or

```
if( answer == 'c' && x > 2 )
```

Because 3 is neither greater-than 3 or less-than-or-equal to 2.

For what it is worth you have over complicated the solution in any case; it is full of repeated tests for conditions you know already to be true, and test for things that you know already to be true due to previous conditions being false. What you could do (an naïve improvement):

```
    if(answer =='c' )
    {
        if( x < 3 )
        {
            printf("You don't drink a lot of coffee, do you?");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You drink a lot of coffee!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( x < 3 )
        {
            printf("You don't drink a lot of tea, do you?");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You drink a lot of tea!");
        }
    }
```

What I'd probably do:

```
    if( x < 3 )
    {
        printf( "You don't drink a lot of %s, do you?", 
                answer == 'c' ? "coffee" : "tea" ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You drink a lot of %s!", 
                answer == 'c' ? "coffee" : "tea" ) ;
    }
```